# how to keyframe subdivide attributes

Tags: animation, keyframes, subdivision-surface

[image]

hello great family, I just wanna know how can I keyframe these attributes I've tried geo nodes but still can't, thanks in advance

Comment: Yes you need to use geonodes, or give your object a Subdivision Surface modifier and in that case you can keyframe the Levels values